# Pandas - How to subtract row values based on other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Input:

```
  Symbol  Type  Value
0   AAPL   BUY    400
1   AAPL  SELL    310
2   INFY  SELL    190
3    JSL   BUY    120
4    JSW   BUY    190
5    JSW  SELL    170
6    REL   BUY    110
7    TCS   BUY    210
8    TCS  SELL    200
```

Desired Output:

```
 Symbol  Type  Value
0   AAPL   BUY     90
2   INFY  SELL    190
3    JSL   BUY    120
4    JSW   BUY     20
6    REL   BUY    110
7    TCS   BUY     10
```

How do I achieve this output in pandas? I tried groupby but that worked for Value column. I want to subtract rows based on Symbol+Type for Value. Like (Symbol+BUY->Value) minus (Symbol+Sell->Value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try

```
df.Value *= np.where(df.Type=='BUY', 1, -1)
out = df.groupby('Symbol', as_index=False).agg({'Type':'first','Value':'sum'})
out
Out[152]: 
  Symbol  Type  Value
0   AAPL   BUY     90
1   INFY  SELL   -190
2    JSL   BUY    120
3    JSW   BUY     20
4    REL   BUY    110
5    TCS   BUY     10
```

If need convert the sell to pos

```
out.Value *= np.where(out.Type=='BUY', 1, -1)
out
Out[157]: 
  Symbol  Type  Value
0   AAPL   BUY     90
1   INFY  SELL    190
2    JSL   BUY    120
3    JSW   BUY     20
4    REL   BUY    110
5    TCS   BUY     10
```

Comment: It worked. It took some time to understand it. Still figuring out why did you use *= operator...

Answer (score 1):

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(index='Symbol', columns='Type', values='Value', aggfunc='sum').\
    fillna(0).eval('Value = BUY - SELL').drop(columns=['BUY', 'SELL']).reset_index()
    
df2.insert(1,'Type', np.where(df2['Value'] > 0, "BUY", "SELL"))
df2['Value'] = abs(df2['Value'])
```

```
Type Symbol  Type  Value
0      AAPL   BUY   90.0
1      INFY  SELL  190.0
2       JSL   BUY  120.0
3       JSW   BUY   20.0
4       REL   BUY  110.0
5       TCS   BUY   10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is the best solution, but it should definitely work:

you can use Numpy to convert your pandas matrix to an array, through which you can loop through, search values, etc. For your example of havin the Columns of the type Buy and the next row of the type Sell subtract (I hope I'm getting your problem right here, sorry for any misconceptions), you could simply use a for loop that makes two arrays, one of the type Sell and one of the type Buy, and then Subtracts Value of 1 from the first array and Value of 1 from the second or something like that. It is definitely not as good as the other answer for this question, at least not in this case, but I do believe that it has cases where this could be a lot better, like for example because numpy lets you reshape the array

Comment: Looping doesn't seem like the best option. And in any case, OP will most likely find more helpful some code showing how this could be done